# I need to open the the file explorer on the click of a CUSTOM BUTTON so that i can select a file. And that file name has to appear in the INPUT field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

The below is code, So on click of the Button the windows explorer has to open and what ever the file is selected from the windows explorer. Needs to show in the INPUT. File type should not be 'File'

```
<Grid.Column width={8}>    
<Input placeholder='File Name - (automatically pick up from file)' fluid style={{marginBottom:'15px'}}/>
<Button content='Browse files' onClick={onButtonClick} size='medium' basic color='blue' icon='download'/>
</Grid.Column>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a file input and place it inside a button tag which you can customize to look however you want. Put a ref on the file input. When you click on the button, you can then call the click() method of file input, which will open the file explorer. You can select the file using the `files` property of file input and set it to a variable.

```js
export default function App() {
  const fileRef = React.useRef();
  let [file, setFile] = React.useState();
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setFile(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => fileRef.current.click()}>
        <input id="upload" name="upload" type="file" ref={fileRef} hidden
          onChange={handleChange} />
        Upload File
      </button>
      { file &&  file!==undefined && file!==null &&
        <div>
          <p>{file.name}</p>
          <p>{file.size}</p>
          <p>{file.type}</p>
        </div>
      }    
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check out [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) for more file properties you can access